# Assembly instruction to and a register and a hex value

Tags: assembly, hex, reverse-engineering

I just started to learn assembly and started looking over some basic program. I ran into a line I didn't understand why it was there and what it meant?

```
and    ecx, -2147483647 ; 8000000TH
```

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is not clear? The comment?

Comment: It does a [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) of the contents of the `ECX` register with the constant value `-2147483647`. The comment portion, after the semicolon, just tells you what that value is in hexadecimal. (That's what the trailing `H` means. I suspect the `T` there is just a typo.)

Comment: The "T" should be 1 => `80000001H` as that is equal to -2147483647. One of possible interpretation of such operation is "keep first and last bit of ecx", and you can for example use conditional jumps to decide which of the two are left set (based on the flag results of `and` instruction): `jz noneSet`, `js topSet`, `jpo lowSet`, `jg onlyLowSet`, ... don't see any simple test for both set (but `jg` + `jpo` after would filter that).

Comment: And as with any other particular ASM instruction, it doesn't do anything significant, just adjusts the internal state of CPU or content of memory in defined deterministic way. Anything "interesting" is achieved by using several instructions modifying bigger portion of the machine state (often whole blocks of memory, which is then interpreted by for example OS code as text string to be displayed on screen, which means that further hundreds of instructions will recalculate the string bytes into video memory content, which will turn desired pixels on LCD to particular color forming chars), etc.